# Reference: Finsler Derivative?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, banach-spaces

On the wikipedia page "Generalizations of derivative" the author mentions: *" in Finsler geometry, one studies spaces which look locally like Banach spaces. Thus one might want a derivative with some of the features of a functional derivative and the covariant derivative."*

My question is what does this derivative look like, explicity (for a Finsler manifold over a general Banach space)?

Can someone provide a reference also, much appreciated.

Comment: a nonlinear connection that defines the covariant derivative in Finsler geometry is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finsler_manifold#Canonical_spray_structure_on_a_Finsler_manifold) --- is this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 2 in Bao, Chern, Shen: *An Introduction to Riemann-Finsler Geometry* may give you the answer.